# Spring HTML codes instead ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: spring, html, encoding

i have a problem with encodings in my spring project. Right now i run jvm (tomcat) with -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 parameter. In my .jsp file are lines:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="true" %>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

In web.xml i defined encoding filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>ISO-8859-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when i pass values with polish letters like łśćżź i have a problem. In my java controller printed (and saved in DB) values are with html codes instead polish letters. For example

**aaalłłł**
is saved as 
**aaal[am]#322;[am]#322;[am]#322;**
I write [am] instead ampersand sign.

I checked that [am]#322; is HTML code for ł letter.
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving data to the database and before that, the data in normal view, check the DB encoding, i.e.:

```
CREATE DATABASE table DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' DEFAULT COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

Also, check the URL table, i.e.:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"
```

If problem are not saving data to the DB, try set lines in jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

In extreme cases, suggest to use ajax with json, setting any encoding.